# Proof of commutation relation in Lattice Vertex Operator Algebra

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, commutator, analyticity

In DGM [1] on page 548 below Equation 5.4, it is claimed that the operators $\frac{dX^j(z)}{dz}$ and $\frac{dX^k(\zeta)}{d\zeta}$ commute, where

\begin{equation}
X^j(z)=q^j-i p^j \log z+i \sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{a_n^j}{n} z^{-n}\tag{3.4}
\end{equation}

and the commutation relation between the modes are

\begin{equation}
\left[a_m^i, a_n^j\right]=m \delta^{i j} \delta_{m,-n}
\tag{3.1}\end{equation}

and $p^{j}$ commutes with all modes. This result is obvious when $j \neq k$, however when $j = k$, after using the commutation relation of modes we get

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n z^{n-1} \zeta^{-n-1}
\end{equation}
which does not converge in either of the regions $|z| > |\zeta|$ or $|\zeta| > |z|$.

[1] Conformal field theory of twisted vertex operators - Dolan, Goddard, Montague;   https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(90)90644-S